# Elements get overlapped instead of shifting down when doing a flex wrap

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, responsive

I was making my website responsive for mobile view so I added a flex-wrap for wrapping things when the browser resizes but there is a button beneath the wrapper div and it doesn't move down and it overlaps. Here is a similar code :

```
<div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexFlow: "row wrap"
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          height: "60px",
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "row",
          flexWrap: "wrap",
          width: "100%",
          border:"1px solid black",
          
        }}
      >
        <div>Test2</div>
        <div>Test2</div>
        <div>Test2</div>
        <div>Test2</div>
        <div>Test2</div>
        <div>Test2</div>
        <div>Test2</div>
        <div>Test2</div>
        <div>Test2</div>
        <div>Test2</div>
        <div>Test2</div>
        <div>Test2</div>
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          margin:10,
        }}
      >
        <button>hello</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

In the above code when the browser is resized the text gets overlapped with the button and border also doesn't resizes. Kindly help

Comment: i think its the height

Comment: Yes, thanks figured it out